# In Elasticsearch, is there a way to dynamically built and pass a JSON query object?

Tags: json, angularjs, elasticsearch

I am using angularjs and elasticsearch.angular.js. I have build a dynamic JSON query object based on user requests. Is there a way to in ES javascript to pass it to the search api?

In the below example, myJSONQUery is the JSON object.

```
client.search({
index: 'myindex*',
body :{
filtered : {
myJSONQUery
}
}
}).then(function (response) {
console.info(JSON.stringify(response));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes , [search template](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-template.html) is the way to go

You can make templates here , like mustache scripts and then just pass the parameters in the search.

Comment: I am dynamically building boolean "AND" and "OR" query based on name value pairs which are received as part of the request. In the case of same fields, the values we use "OR" and between different fields "AND". I have seen search template, but can we pass a query like this?

Comment: Hi, All who have pondered over this this question and @Vineet, thank you. I have solved this. The above request works. I had an issue because of the way my JSON Object was built. Please note the your JSON Object variable name becomes part of the request.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [elasticsearch query builder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch-query-builder)

`you can dynamically build queries from input`

`you can allow user to type in query itself`